# Laravel: View e SubViews

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Alguém sabe como o meu `layouts.default` pode carregar várias views sempre que são chamadas. Por exemplo quero chamar as views dos menus sendo que o arquivo `menu.blade.php` tem que receber dados também.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Costumo utilizar o método `View::share("variável", "valor");` pra compartilhar variáveis entre todas as views... mas acredito que devam existir métodos melhores...

ex.:

```
//No controller
public function minhaAction(){
   View::share("menu", array(...)); //a variavel $menu estara disponivel em todas as views...
   return ...;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Outra forma seria criar a *View* e passar para a **principal** como?

**`menu.blade.php`**

```
<h1>{{$model['Titulo']}}</h1>
```

**`view.blade.php`**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>View Principal</title>
</head>
<body>
    {{$model['cabeca']}}
    {{$model['menu']}}
    {{$model['rodape']}}    
</body>
</html>
```

**`método de carregamento`**

```
$cabeca = View::make("menu")->with('model', array('Titulo' => 'Cabeça do Site'));
$menu   = View::make("menu")->with('model', array('Titulo' => 'Menu do Site'));
$rodape = View::make("menu")->with('model', array('Titulo' => 'Rodapé do Site'));

return View::make("view")->with('model', array('cabeca' => $cabeca,
                                               'menu' => $menu,
                                               'rodape' => $rodape));
```

***Resultado***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Resultado em Hmtl***

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>View Principal</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Cabeça do Site</h1> 
    <h1>Menu do Site</h1>   
    <h1>Rodapé do Site</h1>
</body>
</html>
```